# Does rooting erase?

Tags: rooting

Does rooting your phone inevitably erase all of your data? Im not sure. If so I will have to make a back up. I tried rooting once but I bricked my phone. Thankfully, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rooting your android device won't erase any data, but it is recommenced that you perform a data backup in event that your device becomes bricked or data accidentally erased.